# php and html - how to align horizontally

Tags: php, html, css

I just wanna ask on how can i align them horizontally.

**Output:**

[image: here is the output of the code below]

**Source Code:** 
Connected to mysql, The mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array.

```
<?php

$fetch_vehicle = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM vehicle") or die("Error: Could not fetch rows!".mysqli_error($connect));

echo'<br><br><br>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_vehicle)) {

    if(strcasecmp($row['brand'], 'toyota') == 0)

    echo '<div id="div" style = "margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;"> 
    <img src="../images/car/'. $row['image'].'" height="200" width="400" class="image"
    border="0" alt=""/> 
    <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">'.$row["brand"].' '.$row["model"].'</h1>
    '.$row['description'].' 
    </div><br><br><br><br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you marking this question for `php` and `html` while it's clearly a `css` problem? I fixed it for you this time, but please use proper tags for future questions.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please. No need for your PHP in this post. And do you have any additional CSS?

Comment: i already add the css file badly need help

Answer (score 0):

First, this is going to create multiple `#div` divs, and an ID can only exist on the page once. So I changed that to a class instead. Second, you should remove the `height` and `width` attributes from the `img` and put those in CSS instead. Isn't necessary, but recommended as a best practice. And then you want to set the `.div`'s to have a `width` or `max-width` that matches the `img` width, so that those divs don't grow beyond the width of the image. From there, here are a few solutions to put them in a horizontal row. I'm assuming that's what you mean by "align horizontally".

You can set `float: left` on the divs.

```css
.div {
  max-width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
.div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Or set the divs to `display: inline-block`.

```css
.div {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>

<div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
  <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Or you can introduce a parent element and use `display: flex` on the parent. And if by "align horizontally", you wanted to center these horizontally, also use `justify-content: center;` on the `.flex` parent.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.div {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
    <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>

  <div class="div" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="image" border="0" alt="" />
    <h1 style="color:white; margin-left: 10; margin-top: -20px;">title</h1> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the align horizontally means i want the first picture to be on the side of the other one

Comment: like
 ---------------------    --------------------
|                         |   |                         |
|    Picture 1       |   |     Picture 2      |   also picture 3 and 4 here
|                         |   |                         |
 ---------------------   ---------------------
 ---------------------    --------------------
|                         |   |                         |
|    Picture 5       |   |     Picture 6      |   also picture 7 and 8 here
|                         |   |                         |
 ---------------------   ---------------------

Comment: @qwertqwert so... centered?

Comment: i just want to have a positioning like you have rows and column like 3 columns and 3 rows

Comment: @qwertqwert updated the first solution with an example for 3x3.